# Java iterator to email string images?

Tags: java, string, iterator

I am sending out an email that gets a variety number of images from a db. The email will be sent from putting Strings together. There is a

```
 String topEmail;
 String middleEmail: (This needs to be all the images)
 String bottomEmail;
```

The email message will b

```
 String emailMessag = topemail + middleEmail + bottomEmail;
```

I am using this to iterate the images

```
 while (scdIterator.hasNext()) {
  middleEmail= "<div><img src=\"someimg1.jpg"\" height=\"115\"></div>";
 }
```

and need no matter how many image there are the outcome to be

example

```
 <div><img src=\"someimg1.jpg"\" height=\"115\"></div>
 <div><img src=\"someimg2.jpg"\" height=\"115\"></div>
 <div><img src=\"someimg3.jpg"\" height=\"115\"></div>
```

Comment: What's "scdIterator" ? Where do the image file names come from? What exactly is your question? What part do you need help with?

Comment: You are iterating over something, but not actually reading the values from the iterator

Comment: You're setting a String over and over to be the same thing, and then wonder why it's ... the same thing?

Comment: scditerator is information about the products that are in a shopping cart. I then get just the image names of the products using a MMObj. I want to get all the images and sent them in an email. The email message is sent as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You keep replacing `middleEmail` with a totally new value, instead of appending new information to the end of the previous value.  In other words, you need to gradually build up a String from its parts.  In Java, the typical way to build up a String piece-by-piece is to use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Try something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (scdIterator.hasNext()) {
  Object part = scdIterator.next();
  // modify this line to use the value we just got from the iterator somehow
  sb.append("<div><img src=\"someimg1.jpg"\" height=\"115\"></div>");
}
String middleEmail = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually say what your problem is, but... you are iterating over something, but not actually reading the values from the iterator.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
while (scdIterator.hasNext()) {
  middleEmail= "<div><img src=\""+scdIterator.next()+"\" height=\"115\"></div>";
}
```

...if your iterator returns filenames

(and see gteff's answer about StringBuilder - you need that too)

Answer (score -1):

Its always better not to construct html strings inside java code, you could use any templating  engine like StringTemplates, which can help you.